# copy file/files from a docker container using ssh

Tags: docker

I run this command:

```
ssh deployer@x.xx.xxx.xxx docker cp mkb-be:/home/node/mkb-be/logs/2021-06-21.info.log.gz /tmp/
```

But it copies the file into the tmp dir located on the remote server, how do I make it land it in the same directory but located on my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

To copy files from docker container you can write your command in the below format

```
docker cp <container>:<src-path> <local-dest-path> 
kubectl cp <your-pod-name>:<src-path> <local-dest-path>
```

for example:

```
docker cp sitecore-xm1_cm_1:"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\logs" "C:\" 
kubectl cp k8s-xm-cm-pod:some-file.txt "C:\"
```

By looking into the command which you are using I think you need to specify the full path of the file location in the local machine.